# Displaying data in table asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table, grid.mvc

I want to show data events into a table 
Before that i was able to show them without using a table inside 
But now i want to show in a table 
so far now i am able to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfTBg.jpg)

But i want to place "Faliure" under "Name" and 1st time in occur and second time in recover

Here is my controller code where i am getting the events

```
 SqlDataReader reader_events = event_command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader_events.Read())
                {
                    events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]));
                    events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]));
                    events.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine));
                    //events.Add(string.Concat(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]) + " - " +" Occur " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + " - " + " Recover " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)));

                    //events.Add(string.Concat(" Power Failure " + " Event ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_ID"]) + " Device ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Device_ID"]) + " Occur at " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + " Recover at " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)));
                    //events.Add(string.Concat(" Power Failure " + " Event ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_ID"]) + ", Device ID # " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Device_ID"]) + ", Occured " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]) + ", Recover " + Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5)));
                }
```

i have passed the events in view data as

```
 ViewData["events"] = events;
```

in my layout(view) i have done this

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                         Name
                      </th>
                      <th>
                          Occur
                      </th>
                      <th>
                          Recover
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewData["events"] as List<string>)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td style="border:1px solid black">
                                    @Html.DisplayTextFor()
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <b style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-family:'Agency FB'; font-size:small; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">

                                        </b>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

what i am missing? 
any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE:**

Here what i get

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8UYY.jpg)

Name is coming from one table while occur and recover from another table

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Occur
                </th>
                <th>
                    Recover
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>@{
                if (ViewData["Data"] != null)
                {
                    if (ViewData.Values != null && ViewData.Values.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in ViewData["Data"] as List<string>)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td style="border:1px solid black">
                                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Name);

                                    <fieldset>
                                        <b style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-family:'Agency FB'; font-size:small; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">

                                        </b>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border:1px solid black">
                                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Occur);
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <b style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-family:'Agency FB'; font-size:small; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">

                                        </b>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border:1px solid black">
                                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Recover);
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <b style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-family:'Agency FB'; font-size:small; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">

                                        </b>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }</tbody>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i can't use model=> item. as i am using view data, plus the data is coming from 2 tables